# Why does Python ecosystem have inconsistent fileIO?

Tags: python, opencv, oop, design-patterns

To load csv data from a file, we have:

```
file = open(path)
reader = csv.reader(file)
```

Similarly to load json data, we have:

```
file = open(path)
data = json.load(file)
```

In both the cases, we are using `file` object as the base abstraction to build upon. Thinking this in OOPs and modular terms also makes sense since csv and json files are basically string files with additional properties.
So, it appears bad to have something like `read = csv.reader(path)` or `data = json.load(path)` as an alternative implementation choice just to reduce 1 line of fileIO code, while losing the functionality & flexibility of the "file objects."

But when I see binary files IO with this perspective, it doesn't appear that packages handling them are always following the same logic.

As an instance to load an image in opencv we do `image = cv2.imread(path)` instead of

```
file = open(path, 'b')
image = cv2.imread(file)
```

Same is the case in PIL module.

Aren't images binary files which can utilize implementation benefits of bytes IO provided by the standard library?

Comment: Opening the file for you in the right mode is just convenience some libraries provide.

Comment: @timgeb My question is why opencv and PIL are providing more "convenience" than csv and json modules?

Comment: PIL and OpenCV are not standard library modules. They are developed by different people who make different design decisions.

Comment: Besides, Python is not an OOP language. So whatever opinions (and in my experience, from the ancient time I cared about those dogma fight, even in true OOP languages, those opinions are very subjective, changing and contradictory) about how it should be in OOP seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: @chrslg but all this time I've been hearing that everything in python is an object?

Comment: There are many languages that use the word "object" to designed data, and that are not OOP. "OOP" implies heavy usage of methods, inheritance, polymorphism, etc. Even if, under the hood, everything is an object, does not make Python OOP language. Most python program don't even define a class, and certainly not polymorphism. It's more a multi-paradigm language. Like C++ (read what Stroustrup said about C++ not being OOP), with even less emphasis on OOP.

Comment: Not that this is a subjective debate. An opinion-based questions are not in the scope of SO anyway.

Comment: @timgeb Do you mean that if opencv and pil were a part of standard library then there had been a better chance of them implementing the alternate interface?

Comment: OpenCV is a c++ library with a thin, mostly autogenerated Python wrapper. Doesn't really make much sense to expect that to use Python file IO -- just a bunch of work reimplementing something that already exists, works, and is tested,.... to accomplish what exactly (other than likely lower performance due to interactions with the interpreter)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you might have different reading operations that you want to perform.

With `json` and `csv` there might be options that you want to pass to the reading part or other things that you want to do with the open file. This can't be generalized for every user. For example, `json.load` accepts `parse_float` and `parse_int` arguments among others. That's up to the use case to pass these optional args when reading, so it makes sense that this is left to the user. When reading an image with PIL instead, there is not much you need to customize, you just load the pixel values, so there it makes sense to hide the opening and closing of the file.

If you only wish to read it all, and never need optional args for your use case, then you can typically implement your simple reading function and go with that:

```
def json_load(path):
   with open(path) as f:
       return json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not always want to parse a file.

Sometimes it could be data from the network or other sources.
In this case, you could use for example `StingIO` or any other kind of buffer which will be ok to duck-type instead of a file descriptor.

So passing on the file does `.read()` and maybe a couple of other methods from that object

It might not be that obvious compared to the interfaces or traits from statically typed languages as you don't know what the parser will do to your argument.

As python does not guarantee you type safety, Unfortunately, the only way around the existing codebase is to get familiar with the tools you'd like to use and accept them.